# Autohotkey simulate scroll lock being pushed twice

Tags: autohotkey

Basically I am trying to write a script that will simulate holding down control and pushing scroll lock twice. I just can't seem to get it right.

Tried

```
Send, {Ctrl Down}{ScrollLock}
Send, {ScrollLock}{Ctrl Up}
return
```

And

```
Send, {Ctrl Down}{ScrollLock}{ScrollLock}{Ctrl Up}
return
```

But neither trigger the desired response.

Comment: It might help to specify what the desired response is (e.g. in what application?).

Comment: @Gilles; There's a "manual BSOD" function in windows activated by holding **right** control and double tapping scroll lock. Perhaps the asker wants an extreme boss key?

Comment: @Phoshi I am working with the manual BSOD lol but not for an extreme boss key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild guess: maybe the application requires a delay between the presses. Try adding `Sleep 1000` (1 second, if it works you can try shortening the delay) between the two `Send` commands.

Second wild guess: are you trying to get a KVM to react? If so, Autohotkey won't help directly, because it simulates keyboard events at the OS level, not the keyboard level. (I've seen KVMs that require two <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> presses with a little delay, but they don't need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, they react on the LED changes rather than the key presses).

Comment: Thanks I will try the delay and no not a KVM. I am trying to BSOD a test machine with the MS regedit.

Comment: @MrStatic: there's a good chance that the key combination is intercepted directly in the keyboard driver, at a lower level than AutoHotkey's key injection. There may be a way to generate a manual BSOD through an API call rather than the keyboard driver, you could try asking that question. If there isn't you could run your test system in a virtual machine and send the keyboard events from outside the VM.

Comment: Thanks, I gave you an upvote but can't accept. I will probably end up asking the new question.