# Manually BSOD a Windows 7 Machine

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I am trying to manually BSOD a machine for some testing. [I already](https://superuser.com/questions/173006/autohotkey-simulate-scroll-lock-being-pushed-twice) attempted to use the Registry edit with autohotkey to no avail. I need to pull this off via a script/batch or some other way that can be scripted.

Comment: Are you using a USB keyboard?

Comment: AutoHotkey will not work because the Ctrl-ScrollLock code is contained inside the keyboard driver (which AutoHotkey obviously bypasses).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *knew* that there was a way to to it. I seemed to recall, from many (many!) years ago in my early Windows development days, a simple API call that would cause a system to "blue screen." It's in the Windows DDK. You're looking for KeBugCheck or KeBugCheckEx. It's intended for use by device drivers and will cause the system to break if there's a debugger attached. If there's no debugger, the system will BSOD. Here's the Microsoft article that describes it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551948(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could probably download and install the debugging tools, then script the '.crash' command. I'm not sure the specifics of doing this, but it sounds feasible.

Sources;

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667581/simulating-a-bluescreen

Comment: I was thinking...and would guess that if you cannot find a way to script the .crash command directly, you might be able to build a program that finds the WinDbg window and sends keystroke messages to it. I dunno how this works on Windows 7, but it used to be somewhat straightforward on XP using the Win32 API. I might be doable in VBS too, not sure. I haven't played with Windows 7 much.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain Sysinternal's Process Explorer, run it as administrator, and kill `winlogon.exe`.  Won't be a "traditional" blue screen though.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy tool for manual BSOD is http://download.sysinternals.com/files/NotMyFault.zip
Just run notmyfault /crash